# Reading binary data from CSV file into Numpy array

Tags: python

I have what should be a very simple straightforward question, however I have not found an efficient, pythonic way to solve it yet. I have a CSV file full of rows of 16 bit binary data. For instance, a file might look like the following (where a newline is the delimiter):

```
0101000000000000
0000111011001001
1100101011001100
```

What I ultimately want is to feed this data into a one-dimensional numpy array full of boolean values, such that I can perform bitwise operations on the array with other arrays full of boolean values. Therefore I want the final array to look like:

```
['False', 'True', 'False' ... 'True', 'False', 'False']
```

where the entire contents of the CSV file are in one single array. I have tried using numpy [loadtxt](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html) and [genfromtxt](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html), but can't get anything to work properly. One of the problems is that the entire row is read in as a string, in which case I can't parse the string into binary, OR the row is read in as binary, at which point I cannot break it into individual bits. Any insight or ideas would be greatly appreciated!

I first tried doing:

```
import numpy as np

with open('test_file.csv') as file:
     array = np.loadtxt(file, dtype=bool)
```

however this converts the entire row to a single boolean value, rather than the individual bits of the row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply solution, but given your file inputs above this is one solution;

```
import numpy as np
with open('test_file.csv') as f:
    bools = np.array([bool(int(i)) for line in f for i in line.strip()])
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use a classical *listcomp* with [`np.array`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array.html) :

```
import numpy as np
​
with open("input.csv", mode="r") as f:
    flats = "".join(line.strip() for line in f)
​
barr = np.array([c == "1" for c in flats], dtype=bool)
```

Output :

```
array([False,  True, False,  True, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False,  True,  True,  True, False,  True,  True, False,
       False,  True, False, False,  True,  True,  True, False, False,
        True, False,  True, False,  True,  True, False, False,  True,
        True, False, False])
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want something like this.
Here I respected your delimiters, just in case you want that.

```
import numpy as np
with open('test_file.csv') as file:
     array = np.loadtxt(file, dtype="str")
new_arr = np.array([np.array(list(s)) == "1" for s in array]) #.flatten()
#If you don't want delimited just add .flatten()
```

The new_arr is this:

```
array([[False,  True, False,  True, False, False, False, False, False,
        False, False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False,  True,  True,  True, False,  True,
         True, False, False,  True, False, False,  True],
       [ True,  True, False, False,  True, False,  True, False,  True,
         True, False, False,  True,  True, False, False]])
```